# Difference between "confondere" and "far confondere"

Tags: verbs, word-choice, difference

What is the difference between the following sentences?

- Lui mi confonde.
- Lui mi fa confondere.

Answer (score -1):

- "He confuses me"
- It's an expression used to intend that he's making you lose a bit of your patience, maybe lose a bit of your time, that he's creating you a bit of a mental hassle; I wouldn't know how to translate it better. He's basically creating you problems, but not serious problems. Usually adults use it to describe not collaborative children and/or elder people.

Comment: Welcome on ItalianSE!